# How to define two C structures where one is the prefix of the other

Tags: c, struct, c-preprocessor

I have an existing structure definition

```
struct mystruct{
    int field1;
    int field2;
    int field3; 
};
```

and I want to define a trimmed version of it

```
struct mytrimmedstruct{
    int field1;
    int field2;
};
```

I would like the two definitions to be single-source to avoid going out-of-sync when new fields are added in the future.
I do not want to have a nested struct, meaning a field in mystruct that would be of type mytrimmedstruct, as that would disrupt the way mystruct is currently accessed. For example,

```
struct mystruct{
    struct mytrimmedstruct ts;
    int field3; 
};
```

would change the way field1 and field2 are accessed:

```
myst.ts.field1;
```

rather than

```
myst.field1;
```

Basically, I would like to have the same effect as anonymous structs

```
struct mystruct{
    struct {
        int field1;
        int field2;
    };
    int field3; 
};
```

except that I want to have a name for the 'embedded' structure.
Obviously, this should be achievable with macros, but it will be messy as in my case the structure has a large number of fields with copious amount of comments/documentation.

Comment: This is the hammer-and-nail problem: When you have a hammer, everything looks like a nail. You have a C compiler, so you are attempting to solve this with C shenanigans. Do not do that. Use other software to build the source code you want at build time. E.g, have a file where you write the first sequence of fields and the second sequence of fields, separated by some delimiter, and use Unix command-line tools or something you write yourself or something else to generate the C source code (as a header to be included) from that file. Document it.

Comment: I cannot think of any other way than the macros you suggested, or if C++ is an option to use inheritence

Comment: You already know the 3 options: Manually copy fields, nested struct, or preprocessor trickery. All of these will require some extra work for you, and which you should choose depends on what relationship of these structs are in practice and how they are used. You are only one who can make the choice.

Comment: You can mimic “there is no nested structure here”: `struct mystruct struct mytrimmedstruct nested; int field3; };` / `#define field1 nested.field1` /  `#define field2 nested.field2`. Then later source code can access `struct mystruct` using just `field1` and `field2` for member names. There will be no danger of going out-of-sync since adding new members without defining the corresponding macros would yield compiler errors.

Comment: C++ is not an option, and neither is mimicing a nested structure. The outer structure has currently around 30 fields, and is widely used by numerous APIs. The trimmed version should come in without disrupting the existing code. The goal is to have a lighter weight version because of memory constraints.

Comment: user2414029, "I do not want to have a nested struct, meaning a field in mystruct that would be of type mytrimmedstruct, as that would disrupt the way mystruct is currently accessed."  -->  A nested structure does not certainly change  the way mystruct is currently accessed.

Comment: Please add some examples, how you like to use it, to your question.

Comment: I clarified what I meant by 'I do not want to disrupt the way mystruct fields are accessed'.

Comment: `How to define two C structures where one is the prefix of the other` Repeat the prefix members in both structures.

Answer (score 1):

"but it will be messy" ... Not all that messy...

foo.h

```
/* NO GUARDS HERE */

typedef struct {
    int first;
    int second;
#ifdef BIGTOO
    int third; // doco doco doco
    int fourth;
    /*
    Lots of doco here
    */
    double dbls[10];
} big_t;
#else
} small_t;
#endif
```

foo.c

```
#include "foo.h"
#define BIGTOO
#include "foo.h"
#undef BIGTOO

int main() {
    printf( "sizeof big_t %zu\n", sizeof big_t );

    printf( "sizeof small_t %zu\n", sizeof small_t );

    return 0;
}
```

Output

```
sizeof big_t 96
sizeof small_t 8
```

Comment: `"%zu"`, not `"%d"`, is the matching specifier for `size_t`, the type that results from `sizeof`.  Using  `"%d"` here is _undefined behavior_ (UB).

Comment: This is one way of doing it, thanks. Although, I was hoping for a solution without or with minimal preprocessor intervention.

Comment: @user2414029 Paramount would be that the 'full-sized` and 'prefix' versions are declared in one location. One 'token' and a few '#ifdef`s and your need is fulfilled. With some elaboration, you could even have 3 (or more) different versions: tiny, normal and jumbo...

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Sorry. My old compiler does know about `%zu`... I've change the example to fit with this century... Thanks.

Comment: @Fe2O3 For old compilers a good solution is `printf( "sizeof big_t %lu\n", (unsigned long) sizeof big_t);`.

Answer (score 0):

> How to define two C structures where one is the prefix of the other

There is no language feature to simplify that. You have to include the members from one structure as prefix in the other structure.

How you do that - manually by yourself, hire a monkey to copy it, with some macros or code generation - it's up to you, the result has to be the same. I would stick to C preprocessor to still have IDE features.

```
#define MYTRIMMEDSTRUCT_MEMBERS() \
    int field1; \
    int field2;

struct mytrimmedstruct{
    MYTRIMMEDSTRUCT_MEMBERS()
};

struct mystruct{
    MYTRIMMEDSTRUCT_MEMBERS()
    int field3; 
};
```